# Azure App Service Website Common Name Mismatch Certificate

Tags: azure, certificate, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I have 3 azure app services. They all follow the naming conventions

```
AAA.api.azurewebsites.net
BBB.api.azurewebsites.net
CCC.api.azurewebsites.net
```

I run an online security tests on my 3 websites and I get the following...There is a common name mismatch.

Do i need to upload a custom certificate in azure to fix this?

[image]

Comment: May I know if there is any update in this case?

Comment: @Nancy Yeah, the URL's are completely different. My 3rd party scanning app keeping thinking there is a security vaurtability and throws the above "Mismatch Error on port 8172, which is the webdeploy app ports. I have 20 apps in Azure and they all have the same problem.  I will open a ticket with Microsoft Premium support.

Answer (score 0):

> Do i need to upload a custom certificate in azure to fix this?

I think it's up to you. By default, after you create a web app service on the portal, you can directly use HTTPS to access your websites since there is an SSL certificate with the common name *.azurewebsites.net and subject alternative name for some specific DNS names.

But if you want to map your custom domain to your current web app service, you must upload your custom domain SSL certificate for HTTPS. First, you need [map an existing custom DNS name to Azure Web Apps.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) then you can [bind an existing custom SSL certificate to Azure Web Apps.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl)

### Update

It seems that there is a mismatch between the domain name and the SAN or common name of SSL certificate. You can verify if you have mistyped the URL https://example.com instead of https://www.example.com in the address bar when you see that error. Also, you may get an error if your website shares an IP address with another website that has an SSL certificate but not using an SNI based SSL. It could also be that the client connecting or the server hosting (or both) do not support Server Name Indication (SNI). You can get more details from [GlobalSign Blog](https://www.globalsign.com/en-sg/blog/what-is-common-name-mismatch-error/).

Comment: I dont want to upload a certificate if I dont have too. So why does it think there is a common name mismatch?

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT did you look at the ports? Port 454, 455 and 8172 also give the same common name error for us. Any site we host ends up with "www.mywebsite.com:454 server name is www.mywebsite.com while the certificate is issued to waws-prod-am2-001.api.azurewebsites.windows.net"

Comment: @rfcdejong From OP's update. It seems that his 3rd party scanning app keeps thinking that there is a security vaurtability and throws the above "Mismatch Error". Did you have checked these on your side? I'm afraid I could not understand your question well from your simple description. It would be better if you could post your question so that more people can look for it.